# Can't connect to Exchange Web Services from staging servers via Autodiscovery

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange

I have a hosted Exchange server on Rackspace. I am using it to test Exchange Web Services integrated with my personal web application. Rackspace provides an Autodiscovery URL through which EWS connections can be made.

I can connect just fine locally. However, when I try to test the same functionality on my staging servers (which are Amazon ec2 instances), I do NOT get an API response. In fact, the httpd thread serving the end user just hangs indefinitely, which means the user is not able to load ANY other pages in my app, even after the timeout interval.

I have checked the error/access logs for apache, php, and even my load balancer's access logs. None of these resources provided any insight to the problem.

As I said, I have no problem connecting to the exchange server from my local copy of my web app. Why would this be the case? What do I need to do to fix connectivity on my staging servers?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something in EC2 blocking your access to the EWS URL.  Do you need to open a EC2 firewall port to allow your EC2 box to talk to the EWS server?  I can't imagine that hosted EWS would care where the HTTP request was coming from.

Comment: Not that I know of. I explicitly opened the relevant ports to the Autodiscovery IP just to be sure. Same result.

Comment: Can you telnet from the EC2 host to https on autodiscovery?  it should connect and show blank screen.

Comment: Yes, telnet works, and ping, etc.

Comment: What OS are the EC2 instances?  If their windows can you use IE to goto https://exchange.domain.com/ews/exchange.asmx or if linux use wget.

Comment: to be sure your Exchange server is all setup correctly for web services, be sure to use https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com until it's all green.